# Field concatenation based on group in LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I want concate a times field based on grouping of Userid and dates field using LINQ . i am using VS2010 C#(WPF).

i have a collection in below format.

[image]

and want result like

[image]

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You want to `GroupBy` the UserId, Date and presumably Deptname:

```
_context.Log.GroupBy(l => new { l.UserId, l.dates.Date, l.Deptname })
            .Select(g => new { g.Key.UserId, g.Key.Date, g.Key.Deptname, Log = string.Join(",", g.Select(i => i.times)) });
```

Should select the first `UserId`, `Date` and `Deptname`. Then join the log times together. Haven't checked this but seems like it should work.

Comment: One more thing, I want concat string IN/OUT with time on alternatively  means 1st time with IN and next with OUT like IN-10:33:33 AM,OUT-10:33:39 AM, IN-11:33:33 AM etc