# GroupBy with linq to DataTable

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have the datatable below:

```
DefectTypeId   EntityId      DefectId     Remark
------------------------------------------------
1              29000         100          Defect
2              29000         100          Defect
3              29000         200          Ok
1              30000         100          Defect
2              30000         150          
9              31000         100          Defect
10             31000         100          Defect 
12             31000         200          Ok
```

How to get this table or list with linq?

```
EntityId   Remark
------------------------
29000      Defect, Ok
30000      Defect
31000      Defect, Ok
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I tried this but it doesn't work (Rows are not grouped):

```
Dim query = dt.Select("Remark IS NOT NULL").AsEnumerable().GroupBy(
            Function(r) New With {
                .EntityId = r.Field(Of Integer)("EntityId"),
                .DefectId = r.Field(Of Integer)("DefectId"),
                .Remark = r.Field(Of String)("Remark")
            }).[Select](
            Function(g) New With {
                g.Key.EntityId,
                .Remark = String.Join(",", g.Select(Function(i) i("Remark")))
            })
```

Then I tried this:

```
Dim query = (From row In dt.Select("Remark IS NOT NULL")
             Group By EntityId = row.Field(Of Integer)("EntityId"),
                 DefectId = row.Field(Of Integer)("DefectId"),
                 Remark = row.Field(Of String)("Remark") Into g = Group) _
            .Select(Function(i) New With {
                i.EntityId,
                .Remark = String.Join(",", i.Remark)
            })
```

It is better but it is not yet the expected result. Here is the result:

```
EntityId   Remark
------------------------
29000      Defect
29000      Ok
30000      Defect
31000      Defect
31000      Ok
```

I could get what I want using a foreach after but would like to know if it's possible to get the goal (one row per Entity) in a single Linq instruction. Thank you.

Comment: you want a solution with linq only ? i was thinking of posting a solution outside linq

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you having trouble? Do you not know how to use LINQ on a datatable? Do you not know how to do grouping in linq? Do you not know how to aggregate your data to create the Remark field? Something else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203169/field-concatenation-based-on-group-in-linq

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Field concatenation based on group in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203169/field-concatenation-based-on-group-in-linq)

Comment: It is not duplicate -  lambda functions c# syntax is different from vb especially for beginner.

Comment: Can you do it without Linq?

Comment: Without Linq is also a possible solution. I think with linq it would be more concise.

Comment: @IvanH actually lambda syntax is much more similar to VB than query comprehension syntax, which is significantly different in VB.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your answer and working backwards, you want to group by `EntityId` and join the distinct `Remark`s together. Using your existing lambda query as a basis, just simplify it (though I would do the "Remark IS NOT NULL" in LINQ normally):

```
Dim Ans = dt.Select("Remark IS NOT NULL") _
            .GroupBy(Function(r) r.Field(Of Integer)("EntityId"), Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("Remark")) _
            .Select(Function(rg) New With {
                .EntityId = rg.Key,
                .Remark = String.Join(", ", rg.Distinct())
            })
```

Using some of the advantages of VB Query Comprehension, you could also do:

```
Dim Ans2 = From r In dt.Select("Remark IS NOT NULL")
           Group r.Field(Of String)("Remark") By Key = r.Field(Of Integer)("EntityId") Into Group
           Select New With {.EntityId = Key, .Remark = String.Join(", ", Group.Distinct())}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did it without linq. But I'll try your code next week.