# C# Datatable. Compare data from a column and if it matches, append the data from another column of the corresponding row

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

For Example,
If I have the following datatable,

| Location | First name | Pincode | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sydney | John | 123 | Brian |
| New York | Larry | 456 | Sherry |
| Chicago | Meg | 789 | Linda |
| Dallas | Mark | 012 | Cooper |
| Sydney | Jack | 123 | Brian |
| Dallas | Chandler | 012 | Cooper |
| Sydney | Richard | 123 | Brian |

Here, the 1st column to traverse would be Location. Wherever the Location matches, traverse all the corresponding First Names and keep it in a single row comma separated.

| Location | First Name | Pincode | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sydney | John,Jack,Richard | 123 | Brian |
| New York | Larry | 456 | Sherry |
| Chicago | Meg | 789 | Linda |
| Dallas | Mark,Chandler | 012 | Cooper |

I have stored this In a Datatable variable dt as follows:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"].ToString()))
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(script, sqlConn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 3 * 60;
                        adapter.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please share with us what have you tried so far and where did you get stuck.

Comment: @PeterCsala Thank you. I am not very comfortable with DataTable operations. That is why I needed a suggestion. I have pulled this data from MS-SQL database and added it to a Datatable variable. After that I wanted to perform the action that I asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not have your data in Datatable format the code would be much cleaner.

Something like this should solve your problem

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Location");
dt.Columns.Add("First_Name");

dt.Rows.Add("Sydney", "John");
dt.Rows.Add("New York", "Larry");
dt.Rows.Add("Chicago", "Meg");
dt.Rows.Add("Dallas", "Mark");
dt.Rows.Add("Sydney", "Jack");
dt.Rows.Add("Dallas", "Chandler");
dt.Rows.Add("Sydney", "Richard");

var result = dt
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => x["Location"])
    .Select(group => new 
        { 
            Location = group.Key.ToString(), 
            First_Name = string.Join(",", group.Select(x => x["First_Name"])) 
        });
```

***UPDATED***

If you want to convert your anonymous type back to a datatable you could have a look at [Best Practice: Convert LINQ Query result to a DataTable without looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460654/best-practice-convert-linq-query-result-to-a-datatable-without-looping)

That being said. I feel if you are going this direction it would be better to do this task a different way. maybe write a stored procedure to do the job (1 db call vs 2)

If you want to do it in C# I would change the implementation of this solution to something like this

```
DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
dtResult.Columns.Add("Location");
dtResult.Columns.Add("First_Name");

DataTable dt = dtResult.Clone();
dt.Rows.Add("Sydney", "John");
dt.Rows.Add("New York", "Larry");
dt.Rows.Add("Chicago", "Meg");
dt.Rows.Add("Dallas", "Mark");
dt.Rows.Add("Sydney", "Jack");
dt.Rows.Add("Dallas", "Chandler");
dt.Rows.Add("Sydney", "Richard");

var result = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x["Location"]) 
                 .Select(group => dtResult.Rows.Add(group.Key.ToString(),string.Join(",", group.Select(x => x["First_Name"]))));
```

Comment: There is a minor thing: Even though `group` is not a [reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/) it is better to avoid using it because it might cause confusion whenever one wants to convert lambda expression to query/statement expression.

Comment: Ok. I want to store this processed in a datatable again. How do we do that? PS- The datatable contains more columns. This was just an example to simplify. Assume that value of other columns would be same for a given Location.

Comment: Updated the question for better undertanding of use case.

Comment: I feel like you are heading in the wrong direction then. why not use a stored procedure to do the work? 2 db calls vs 1?

Comment: @PeterCsala The word group is purely used in this example to help him/her understand what the group by and the select is doing. It is expected that people don't copy solution but rather understand and revise. I mean its not like he will copy the dt.rows.add(#####)

Comment: @Neil This was really helpful. Actually I was unable to explain my entire use case. This operation was just a part to simplify the other parts of the process. I got a gist of this and was able to implement it with success. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use GroupBy the Location column and concatenate First Name Column.

Something like

```
_context.Locs.GroupBy(l => new { l.Location })
        .Select(g => new { g.Key.Location , Names = string.Join(",", g.Select(i => i.FirstName)) });
```

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203169/field-concatenation-based-on-group-in-linq)

Comment: Note that this is not a Linq-To-Sql or Linq-To-Entities question. So this just works with a strongly typed DataSet not with a plain DataTable. In that case use Neil's answer